# Rust: Struggling assigning values to some struct attributes inside an "if let" block. I don't understand the compiler error

Tags: rust, reference, option-type

I'm struggling with some apparently silly Rust code.

```
let &mut pal = &mut lbm.palette.colors.get(c as usize);
// IntelliJ says pal is an Option<&RGBAColor>

if let Some( & pal_value) = pal {
    // IntelliJ says pal_value is an RGBAColor

    println!("palvalue.r={}",  pal_value.r);
    pal_value.r = r;
    pal_value.g = g;
    pal_value.b = b;
    pal_value.a = 255;
}
```

I've iterated a lot this structure ("guided" by the rust compiler and IntelliJ helpers), and as far as I understand I think its syntax express what I want:

1.- I have some `RGBAColor` value somewhere else which I borrow here being mutable

2.- as it's an optional value (thanks to get()), I need the "if let" block below

3.- The block below works for reading values, aka the println line, but it complains in the asignations (as the `Some` value is not declared as mutable, so far so good).

Then if I change the `Some` line to this:

```
let &mut pal = &mut lbm.palette.colors.get(c as usize);
// IntelliJ says pal is an Option<&RGBAColor>

if let Some( &mut pal_value) = pal {
    // IntelliJ says pal_value is an RGBAColor

    println!("palvalue.r={}",  pal_value.r);
    pal_value.r = r;
    pal_value.g = g;
    pal_value.b = b;
    pal_value.a = 255;
}
```

the compiler says:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/file_manager_mod/lbm_manager.rs:156:22
    |
156 |         if let Some( &mut pal_value) = pal {
    |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    --- this expression has type `Option<&RGBAColor>`
    |                      |
    |                      types differ in mutability
    |                      help: you can probably remove the explicit borrow: `pal_value`
    |
    = note:      expected reference `&RGBAColor`
            found mutable reference `&mut _`
```

Which I struggle to understand, or how to fix it...

If I change the `Some` line to this:

```
let &mut pal = &mut lbm.palette.colors.get(c as usize);
// IntelliJ says pal is an Option<&RGBAColor>

if let Some( mut pal_value) = pal {
    // IntelliJ says pal_value is an &RGBAColor

    println!("palvalue.r={}",  pal_value.r);
    pal_value.r = r;
    pal_value.g = g;
    pal_value.b = b;
    pal_value.a = 255;
}
```

The compiler complains about palvalue being a reference so I cannot write the rgb values as I intend it to do (and I really agree with it, that's the sad part).
If I change the `palvalue.r = r` lines for a `*palvalue.r = r` it also complains with `u8 type cannot be dereferenced`

After struggling for (literally) 2 hours I cannot find the proper syntax I need to do what I have in mind, which should be a silly struct assignation. Rust compiler messages are much more cryptic than I wanted.

Any hint about where's my faulty code?

NOTE: `RGBAColor` struct already has the `Copy` and `Clone` preprocessor macro attached right before its definition.

Comment: `lbm.palette.colors.get(c as usize)`, I am assuming this is a collection from Rust std lib, if it is then you can use `get_mut(...)` for a mutable reference of `Some(...)` .element. Your collection needs to be mutable also, if it is not, you cannot do any mutable operation.

Comment: What is the type of `lbm.palette.colors`? It is obvious you invested effort into writing the question, please add this small but important detail.

Comment: it's a vec of RGBAColor, which on its turn it's a silly struct made up of 4 u8's.
BTW, Ömer Erden solution was the trick. As he suggested I was using a standard collection (vec), so I wasn't aware the mutability I needed was implied in the get_mut call (I didn't know at the time), but I do now. If @Ömer Erden wants to transform his hint into a fully fledged answer, I'll put said answer as accepted. Rust compiles perfectly and the havoc of &mut's I was using before the "if let" block changed into this:  let mut pal = lbm.palette.colors.get_mut(c as usize); which is much cleaner. Thanks!!